# When you do a remote desktop connect to another pc which pc's processing power do you have?

Tags: computer-networks

Are you just accessing the data and things on the PC you are connecting to or, if it had a better processor/ram/etc, are you able to take advantage of that?

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with computer *science*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remote desktop into another computer you are actually using that computers hardware. You are not running a virtual machine of that computer, which would take your main computers resources.

Comment: Please do not encourage asking blatantly offtopic questions by answering them.

Comment: Sorry about the post not fitting in here, it was the best match for the subject/question that I could think of. Do you know of another stackexchange section that would have been a better for this? If I have any further related questions I'd like to know the proper place to ask. And thank you, SDhaliwal.